# How to clear branches dropdown in GitExtensions

Tags: git-extensions

My branches dropdown (the dropdown between the Repositories dropdown and Stash button) is cluttered with lots of old branches that don't even exist on the remote anymore.

How can I clear this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have a plugin called "Delete obsolete branches" - Tools > Delete obsolete branches.
There you can select and delete branches that were merged into the current trunk.

I rarely use it, so I do not know all nuances of that plugin, and it offers a few different switches. You can probably delete stale branches from other trunks, but I haven't explored it.

Comment: I found it under Plugins> Delete obsolete branches